# Problems with onHorizontalDragEnd DragEndDetails.primaryVelocity

Tags: flutter, dart, swipe, gesturedetector

I'm very new to android development in general, and so forgive me if some of these are obvious answers.

I'm trying to implement a swipe-left / swipe-right functionality to swap between pages in my app. However, I'm running into issues detecting the velocity and using it to determine if a left/right swap was made.

Here's my code, with debugger instructions left in for clarity:

```
onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
  print("Horizontal Drag Start - preflop.");
},
onHorizontalDragDown: (DragDownDetails details) {
  print("Horizontal Drag Down - preflop.");
},
onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
  print("Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: " + details.primaryDelta.toString());
},
onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
  // TODO: Check velocity for non-zero but still too slow to swap?
  if (details.primaryVelocity >= 0) {
    print("Horizontal Drag End - preflop movement cancelled. Velocity: " + details.primaryVelocity.toString());

    return;
  }
  else {
    print("Horizontal Drag End - preflop. Velocity: " + details.primaryVelocity.toString());

    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Flop()),
    );
  }
}

    onHorizontalDragStart: (DragStartDetails details) {
      print("Horizontal Drag Start - flop.");
    },
    onHorizontalDragDown: (DragDownDetails details) {
      print("Horizontal Drag Down - flop.");
    },
    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
      print("Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: " + details.primaryDelta.toString());
    },
    onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      // TODO: Check velocity for non-zero but still too slow to swap?
      if (details.primaryVelocity <= 0) {
    print("Horizontal Drag End - flop movement cancelled. Velocity: " + details.primaryVelocity.toString());

    return;
      }
      else {
    print("Horizontal Drag End - flop. Velocity: " +
        details.primaryVelocity.toString());

    Navigator.pop(context);
      }
    }
```

When it works correctly, this is the debug output I get:

```
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Down - preflop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Start - preflop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -5.712890625
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -5.336216517857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -7.998046875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -11.42578125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -11.049107142857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -11.049107142857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -13.334263392857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -11.42578125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -7.998046875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -5.336216517857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -3.427734375
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - preflop. Velocity Delta: -4.5703125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag End - preflop. Velocity: -710.2030737630879
```

There are two primary issues I'm facing. Firstly, sometimes, even though I'm properly swiping, the `primaryVelocity` is returning zero. This can be witnessed by tracing the `onHorizontalDragUpdate` and then seeing the resulting `onHorizontalDragEnd`. Now, I understand that if I drag and then stop, and then release my cursor, the ending velocity will logically be zero - but in this case, I'm not perceptibly pausing - just dragging and releasing.

```
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Down - flop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Start - flop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.85546875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -7.998046875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -9.906529017857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -9.140625
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -7.998046875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -5.336216517857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.85546875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -4.5703125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -4.193638392857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -2.28515625
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -2.28515625
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag End - flop movement cancelled. Velocity: 0.0
```

The other issue is that sometimes the sign of `primaryVelocity` doesn't seem to be correct. Despite the `onHorizontalDragUpdate` having negative `primaryDelta` values, for example, the resulting `onHorizontalDragUpdate` has a positive value for velocity:

```
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Down - flop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Start - flop.
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -12.191685267857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -11.42578125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -14.476841517857167
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -13.334263392857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -11.049107142857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.85546875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.85546875
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -4.193638392857139
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -3.427734375
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -3.427734375
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -1.142578125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -1.142578125
I/flutter (17305): Horizontal Drag End - flop. Velocity: 58.203062840330496
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Let me know if there's any additional code I can provide to help answer the questions. Thanks!

**EDIT**

As suggested by Ulas, I updated all of my plugins/IDE. It seems like the first problem has been resolved - I'm not getting the 0.0 velocity anymore.

I am, however, still getting the second problem:

```
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Down - flop.
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Start - flop.
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.478794642857167
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -7.998046875
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857167
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -9.140625
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -9.906529017857167
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -10.283203125
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -13.334263392857167
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -13.334263392857167
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -14.476841517857139
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -12.191685267857139
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -10.283203125
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -12.191685267857139
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -10.283203125
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -8.763950892857139
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -6.85546875
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -5.336216517857139
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -4.5703125
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -3.427734375
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -3.427734375
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -1.9084821428571388
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: -1.142578125
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag Update - flop. Velocity Delta: 0.0
I/flutter (18942): Horizontal Drag End - flop. Velocity: 220.44058450541567
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any 0.0 velocity with your code, Can you try other flutter channels like beta and upgrade latest

Comment: Hi Ulas, I updated to the latest version and that does seem to fix the 0-velocity problem. However I'm still experiencing the other one.